# How do I install VirtualBox's deb package?

Tags: package-management, virtualbox

I have downloaded virtualbox.deb package. But I don't know how to install this application. Please anyone let me know how to install it..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Double clicking it should open it in the Software Centre. That should give you the option to install.

Comment: With **6.1.34_Ubuntu r150636** already installed via official Ubuntu repos, double clicking on the **6.1.38** will only open the "Software Center", indicating that VirtualBox is already installed... :/ Would it be possible to install the deb separately to the standard installation? Cf. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1427770/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-virtualbox-via-gui and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1988473

Answer (score 6):

try this: `sudo dpkg -i YourDebPackage.deb`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`gdebi`](https://launchpad.net/gdebi), a tool similar to dpkg that also resolves any dependencies needed for the package to work.

You just need to install gdebi (`sudo apt-get install gdebi`), and then run:

```
sudo gdebi /PATH/TO/PACKAGE.deb
```