# gnome-shell crashes repeatedly after virtualbox update

Tags: virtualbox, gnome-shell

I am using virtualbox 6.1.34 with Ubuntu 22.04 host and guest and gnome-shell started crashing about every minute.
It worked fine for years and I don't know what changed exactly.

I copied the vm over to another PC with the same virtualbox and there it works fine.

What I see happening as a user is that the window I focus on suddenly gets switched and I don't see the top bar for a short time.

Maybe it has something to do with the graphics drivers. Is there a way to confirm that?
I tried several proprietary NVIDIA drivers and the generic driver with the same result.

What I can see in the log, but I cannot make sense of (see below for the full messages):

> 1. Can't update stage views actor...
> 2. Error looking up permission:... No entry for geolocation
>    3.ATK Bridge is disabled but a11y has already been enabled.
> 3. Unset XDG_SESSION_ID, getCurrentSessionProxy() called outside a user session. Asking logind directly.
> 4. Failed to create file /run/user/1000/gnome-shell-disable-extensions:... File exists

1 - I get that a lot but could not find out what it means.

2 - I don't care about geolocation, or? Can I disable the app that leads to this error to make sure it's not related?

3/4 - What does this even mean? Is it related?

5 - That file does not exist, so I don't know why it complains that it exists and I don't know if it's related.

This is part of `journalctl /usr/bin/gnome-shell`:

```
Sep 05 16:17:01 my-virtualbox gnome-shell[2868]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowGroup>:0x561299fa4360] is on because it needs an allocation.
Sep 05 16:17:01 my-virtualbox gnome-shell[2868]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x56129b810750] is on because it needs an allocation.
Sep 05 16:17:01 my-virtualbox gnome-shell[2868]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x56129b8146a0] is on because it needs an allocation.
Sep 05 16:17:31 my-virtualbox gnome-shell[3880]: Running GNOME Shell (using mutter 42.2) as a X11 window and compositing manager
Sep 05 16:17:31 my-virtualbox gnome-shell[3880]: ATK Bridge is disabled but a11y has already been enabled.
Sep 05 16:17:32 my-virtualbox gnome-shell[3880]: Unset XDG_SESSION_ID, getCurrentSessionProxy() called outside a user session. Asking logind directly.
Sep 05 16:17:32 my-virtualbox gnome-shell[3880]: Will monitor session 2
Sep 05 16:17:32 my-virtualbox gnome-shell[3880]: Telepathy is not available, chat integration will be disabled.
Sep 05 16:17:32 my-virtualbox gnome-shell[3880]: Failed to create file /run/user/1000/gnome-shell-disable-extensions: Error opening file “/run/user/1000/gnome-shell-disable-extensions”: File exists
Sep 05 16:17:32 my-virtualbox gnome-shell[3880]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
Sep 05 16:17:33 my-virtualbox gnome-shell[3880]: Can't update stage views actor <overviewGroup>[<StWidget>:0x563b5a5f4340] is on because it needs an allocation.
Sep 05 16:17:33 my-virtualbox gnome-shell[3880]: Can't update stage views actor <overview>[<Gjs_ui_overview_OverviewActor>:0x563b5aff5860] is on because it needs an allocation.
Sep 05 16:17:33 my-virtualbox gnome-shell[3880]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<Gjs_ui_overviewControls_ControlsManager>:0x563b5a807c60] is on because it needs an allocation.
Sep 05 16:17:33 my-virtualbox gnome-shell[3880]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<Gjs_ui_workspaceThumbnail_ThumbnailsBox>:0x563b5a374ce0] is on because it needs an allocation.
Sep 05 16:17:33 my-virtualbox gnome-shell[3880]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<Gjs_ui_workspaceThumbnail_WorkspaceThumbnail>:0x563b5b647490] is on because it needs an allocation.
Sep 05 16:17:33 my-virtualbox gnome-shell[3880]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<ClutterActor>:0x563b5b722fe0] is on because it needs an allocation.
Sep 05 16:17:33 my-virtualbox gnome-shell[3880]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<ClutterActor>:0x563b5b723300] is on because it needs an allocation.
Sep 05 16:17:33 my-virtualbox gnome-shell[3880]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<Gjs_ui_workspaceThumbnail_WindowClone>:0x563b5b723620] is on because it needs an allocation.
Sep 05 16:17:33 my-virtualbox gnome-shell[3880]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<ClutterClone>:0x563b5b86a420] is on because it needs an allocation.
Sep 05 16:17:33 my-virtualbox gnome-shell[3880]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<Gjs_ui_workspacesView_WorkspacesDisplay>:0x563b5b109350] is on because it needs an allocation.
Sep 05 16:17:33 my-virtualbox gnome-shell[3880]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<Gjs_ui_workspacesView_WorkspacesView>:0x563b5b881c10] is on because it needs an allocation.
Sep 05 16:17:33 my-virtualbox gnome-shell[3880]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<Gjs_ui_workspace_Workspace>:0x563b5b8824e0] is on because it needs an allocation.
Sep 05 16:17:33 my-virtualbox gnome-shell[3880]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<ClutterActor>:0x563b5b875f60] is on because it needs an allocation.
Sep 05 16:17:33 my-virtualbox gnome-shell[3880]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<Gjs_ui_windowPreview_WindowPreview>:0x563b5b88e870] is on because it needs an allocation.
Sep 05 16:17:33 my-virtualbox gnome-shell[3880]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<ClutterActor>:0x563b5b88a350] is on because it needs an allocation.
Sep 05 16:17:33 my-virtualbox gnome-shell[3880]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<ClutterClone>:0x563b5b86a760] is on because it needs an allocation.
Sep 05 16:17:33 my-virtualbox gnome-shell[3880]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<StIcon>:0x563b5b895ca0] is on because it needs an allocation.
Sep 05 16:17:34 my-virtualbox gnome-shell[3880]: GNOME Shell started at Mon Sep 05 2022 16:17:32 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Sep 05 16:17:34 my-virtualbox gnome-shell[3880]: Registering session with GDM
```

EDIT: I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 on the guest system and the latest virtualbox extensions.

EDIT: Added output of `journalctl /usr/bin/gnome-shell`

EDIT: Fixed some of the unrelated errors and updated the log to make it more simple to see what the actual problem is.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. I have VirtualBox 6.1.34 and an Nvidia card.

Comment: Do you remember which version you had before updating? I've tried downgrading to 6.1.32, but it didn't help. I want to try downgrading to an even earlier version, or intall a later version via deb.

Comment: @teg_brightly I just move the vm to another PC with the same version and there it works fine, so it is probably something else.

Comment: Sidenote: I've launched another VM, which hasn't received any updates since the bug appeared, and it has the same issue, so it seems it's caused by something in the host / virtualbox.

Comment: Something probably related: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=276883&p=2
https://forum.manjaro.org/t/virtualbox-error-in-the-last-update/113744

Comment: Also: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=106071

Comment: Other related questions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1427770/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-virtualbox-via-gui
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1988473 (from https://askubuntu.com/questions/264292/how-do-i-install-virtualboxs-deb-package#comment2486609_264295)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug is apparently caused by some updates in the 5.15.0-47 kernel. There is a bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1988473

Reportedly, switching to an earlier kernel, such as 5.15.0-46 makes virtualbox guests functional again. Also the bug has been fixed in later Virtualbox versions, such as 6.1.36.

From the above thread:

> I uploaded virtualbox in unapproved queue for focal (20.04) and jammy (22.04).
> Waiting for SRU team to have a look

So it seems a fix is on the way.

It reportedly can affect any virtualbox guests, including Windows, different GNU/Linux distributions.

Possibly related issues and more explanations: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=106071&start=15#p519086

From the above thread:

> It is related to Kernel commit 6e8ec2552c7d which fixes security vulnerabilities.

> My guess is that the latest linux kernel received a greater security enhancement by a redesigned random number generator. That improvement
> is described in detail here:
> https://www.theregister.com/2022/03/21/new_linux_kernel_has_improved/.
>
> The improvement seems to be so important that it has been ported back
> to older kernels still widely used.

> The VirtualBox test builds 6.1.35r151864 (and newer) are supposed to
> support Linux kernels 5.18, 5.17.12+, 5.15.44+, 5.10.119+ and more on
> the host and in the guest.

Related question: [How to install the latest version of VirtualBox (via GUI)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1427770/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-virtualbox-via-gui)

Comment: Thanks, but trying with virtualbox 6.1.38 the vm does not even start up:  `Failed to load R0 module /usr/lib/virtualbox/VMMR0.r0: Unable to locate imported symbol 'SUPR0FpuBegin' for module 'VMMR0.r0' (VERR_SYMBOL_NOT_FOUND).`

Comment: @phobic Do you have virtualbox-dkms 6.1.38 installed?

Comment: Yes. It started working after I restarted the host computer. This is probably one of the worst experiences I had with virtualbox. Thanks a lot for your help :)
Oh, and 6.1.38 can now easily be updated just by running `sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade`.